# Are all React components usable in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There are lots of React components available. How do I know which ones are usable on React Native platform (IOS and Android)?

Comment: When you say components, do you mean things like npm modules?

Comment: I mean everything created with React.createclass  or class X extends Component. I'm asking since I tried to use one called React Gallery, and it works fine on a web page but I doesn't work (it seems) in an IOS test app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web React components use DOM elements to display (ex. div, h1, table, etc) but these are not supported by React Native. You'll need to find libraries/components made specifically for React Native.

I doubt there are components that supports both, thus it should be fairly easy to figure out if it's made for React Native or not. As of now, if the creator does not specifically say that they made for React Native, it probably does not work on React Native.

Comment: Partly correct, but you can read more about it here: http://www.reactnative.com/make-your-react-native-app-work-in-a-browser/  "we're focusing on Components that can be shared between the web version of React and React Native, a concept that isn't something really new, but has been formalized since React v0.14."